# PHP / MYSQL Date will not insert

Tags: php, mysql, date

I am trying to insert a date from a variable into a mysql database. The format of the column is date and it has dates in the column. The dates in the column look like yyyy-mm-dd

my date variable also looks like this however it will not insert the date into the column and even i do not get an error just a white screen.

```
<?php
//here is the code to insert this does not work
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `invoices` (account_id, purchased_date, sales_rep, INV_ID)
VALUES ('".$acctid."', '".$date"','".$row['8']."', '".$invid."' )") or die("load1 -" . mysql_error());
```

```
<?php 
//this does work but it does not have the date.
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `invoices` (account_id, sales_rep, INV_ID)
    VALUES ('".$acctid."', '".$row['8']."', '".$invid."')") or die("load1 -" . mysql_error());
```

not sure what the problem is. I have displayed the $date variable onto the screen and it looks fine ex. 2012-06-01

so I am not sure why it can not insert this into the database.

Comment: What's the error returned by `mysql_query`?

Comment: there is no error returned only a blank white screen.

Comment: where is the `$date` in the second query?

Comment: echo your query with the values instead of variables and share

Comment: i took it out in the second query and it works fine. that was to make sure that the date was the issue.

Comment: when you get stuck with an error like this,you can use `php -a` to paste your code and see what is wrong with it quickly. Works especially well for parse errors like this one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your error is that you have a parse error in this line:

```
VALUES ('".$acctid."', '".$date"','".$row['8']."', '".$invid."' )")
```

Your server has `display_errors` turned off, so you're not seeing the fatal error output.

You can fix it by adding a concatenation operator (`.`) like so:

```
VALUES ('".$acctid."', '".$date."','".$row['8']."', '".$invid."' )")
```

Also, in the future, I find it more readable to write my queries like so:

```
VALUES ('{$acctid}', '{$date}', '{$row['8']}', '{$invid}')
```

If you prefer not to use interpolation (that's the method of string "injection" used above), you could still use concatenation (your original method) but use spaces to make it more readable (and easier to find syntax errors before you try to execute it):

```
"VALUES ('" . $acctid . "', '" . $date . "' , '" . $row['8'] . "', '" . $invid . "')";
```

And before all the haters shun me for suggesting interpolation over concatenation, let me refer you to [this tweet](https://twitter.com/rasmus/status/207856706422706176) by [@rasmus](http://www.twitter.com/rasmus) stating that interpolation is actually faster than concatenation, these days.

Comment: Thank you. UGGGGGGG I can't believe i missed something that simple.

Comment: np, more eyes helps sometimes (:

Comment: you should set `display_errors` to `on` in your php.ini, or use `ini_set('display_errors', 'on);` if you don't have access to it, or only need it temporarily.  Also, `error_reporting(E_ALL)` if you don't already have it (:

Comment: @Steven: you could save precious time just by configuring your PHP environment (see comment above).

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
//here is the code to insert this does not work
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `invoices` (account_id, purchased_date, sales_rep,   INV_ID) VALUES ('".$acctid."', '".$date"','".$row['8']."', '".$invid."' )") or die("load1 -" .     mysql_error());
?>
```

the error is:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING on line 1
```

There is no `.` after `$date`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `new \DateTime('yyyy-mm-dd')`

```
<?php
//here is the code to insert this does not work
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `invoices` (account_id, purchased_date, sales_rep, INV_ID)
VALUES ('".$acctid."', '".new \DateTime('yyyy-mm-dd')."','".$row['8']."', '".$invid."' )") or die("load1 -" . mysql_error());
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `vipanda2`.`invoices` (account_id, purchased_date, sales_rep, INV_ID)
VALUES ('".$acctid."', '".date('Y-m-d',mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m", $date), date("d", $date), date("Y", $date)))."','".$row['8']."', '".$invid."' )") or die("load1 -" . mysql_error());
```